# counting file length in java: FileReader vs. File.length

Tags: java, file, filereader

Why would fr_count and len be different in the code below?

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
int c;
long fr_count = 0;
while ( -1 != (c = fr.read()) ) 
    fr_count++;
long len = new File(filename).length();
```

I've used the code above on two files. Here are the results:

```
test.txt
 FileReader:  263742
 File.length: 265963
output.enc
 FileReader:  146360
 File.length: 212998
```

Comment: Replace `FileReader` by `FileInputStream` and enlighten yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fr_count` is the number of characters you read from the file. `len` is the number of bytes in the file. They're two very different things. E.g. some characters are represented in multiple bytes, and some encodings use a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark). Both of these will make for differences between the number of characters and the number of bytes in a file.

Answer (score 3):

`File.Length` is returning the number of `Bytes` in the file.  Counting `FileReader.read()` is telling you how many characters are in the file.